# Getting MapView to stay within bounds

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Working with a map to only allow panning within a certain set bounds. In my case I want the application to allow the user to pan around just within the bounds of a specific Island. So far I can only achieve the initial loading to start at the specified island but not able to limit the panning ability. Using API 4.X

Comment: What API? 3.X or 4.X?

Comment: I am currently using 4.x API

Comment: I don't have a code sample for you, but you do this by listening to the drag event and setting the view extent if it passes a certain bounding you defined https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#event:drag

Comment: I will look into this reference and see what I can dig up then

Answer (score 1):

[Getting MapView to stay within bounds](https://community.esri.com/thread/229431-getting-mapview-to-stay-within-bounds) was answered on GeoNet with this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Intro to MapView - Create a 2D map - 4.10</title>
  <style>
  html,
  body,
  #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.10/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.10/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView"
    ], function(Map, MapView) {

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "streets"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        zoom: 8,
        center: [15, 65] // longitude, latitude
      });

      view.when(function() {
        limitMapExtent(view);
      });


      function limitMapExtent(view) {
        var initialExtent = view.extent;
        view.watch('stationary', function(event) {
          if (!event) {
            return;
          }
          //If the map has moved to the point where it's center is
          //outside the initial boundaries, then move it back to the
          //edge where it moved out
          var currentCenter = view.extent.center;
          if (!initialExtent.contains(currentCenter)) {

            var newCenter = view.extent.center;

            //check each side of the initial extent and if the
            //current center is outside that extent,
            //set the new center to be on the edge that it went out on
            if (currentCenter.x < initialExtent.xmin) {
              newCenter.x = initialExtent.xmin;
            }
            if (currentCenter.x > initialExtent.xmax) {
              newCenter.x = initialExtent.xmax;
            }
            if (currentCenter.y < initialExtent.ymin) {
              newCenter.y = initialExtent.ymin;
            }
            if (currentCenter.y > initialExtent.ymax) {
              newCenter.y = initialExtent.ymax;
            }
            view.goTo(newCenter);
          }
        });
      }

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```